# IE/Edge crashes with "Unspecified error" at first line of <script> block

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am trying to implement a very obscure Payment Gateway which relies on some very poor javascript code. It works in Google Chrome, but gets stuck in both IE11 and Edge at the exact same line:

`document.charset = "utf-8";`

The error shown in IE/Edge is: `SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.`

Here is a screenshot of the error in process:
[image: Screenshot]

I am not even sure why they are trying to set the character encoding this way. I am pretty sure that line could just be omitted.
What can I do here? I cannot edit their code (which is executed in a popup window), but I have control over the parent page that initiates the popup window.

Comment: Odd, both IE11 and Edge allow to modify `document.charset` via the console ..?

Comment: Must be some other factor. Maybe it would crash even if that line was not there. I have tried setting a breakpoint and "stepping over" that line, but it does not seem to be able to do that (crashes at the line when I click step over).

Comment: Oddly enough, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/characterSet says this was a read-only property. (Apart from that it is a legacy alias for `document.characterSet`, but that’s read-only as well, according to specs, https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-characterset)

Comment: @Teemu yes, but as it says there, _“The properties `document.charset` and `document.inputEncoding` are legacy aliases for `document.characterSet`. Do not use them anymore.”_ - I would imagine that `document.charset` would have been read-only already. (And I can’t really see much sense in setting it to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe Yeah ... Setting it seems to fail silently in FF, but Edge and IE set it just like that, no complains at all, though no affect can be seen.

Comment: Can you check what value is returned, when you try and read the property before that line? Is your system using UTF-8 throughout, or is the popup maybe opened with a different one initially?

Comment: @CBroe Just tried it. At the breakpoint (before executing) both `charset` and `characterSet` properties are already set to "utf-8". I also checked the `Content-Type` response header for that specific POST request and it is received as "text/html; charset=utf-8". Oh and yes my system is using UTF-8 throughout.

Comment: I ran the snippet on my server, yet no errors with IE or Edge, they just seemingly set a new character set, the "read-only" property seems to be ignored. In FF writing the value silently fails ... Is it possible, that IE and Edge point to a wrong error line ..? IE has done it before, not sure about Edge.

Comment: I just noticed something.  The `<script>` tag is not properly terminated. Seems to just cut off at `</sc`. That could very well be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for IE behaving this way was an incorrectly terminated `<script>` container. Notice in the screenshot how it ends with `</sc`.

In my case this is  due to a *server error* which caused the page to be rendered incompletely (thus the cut-off in the middle of a closing tag).

Interestingly Chrome and Firefox were still able to execute the script without any issues. I think IE actually reacted correctly in this case, but unfortunately with a very unhelpful message.